# Replacing dataframe value with array

Tags: python, pandas

I have a time series dataframe that i want to predict with LSTM but i cant replace the train and test value with the scaled value.

This is the dataframe

[image: train dataframe]

and this is the scaled data

[image: scaled data]

How can i put the scaled value replacing the value in train dataframe ?Since the index is a date and i cant do loop to replacing the data. and i cant replace data in dataframe either.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a couple of methods, if you want to reassign the data you can create a new dataframe and set the indicies to `ts_train_scaled` with a command like

```
pd.Dataframe(data=ts_train_scaled, index=ts_train.index)
```

If you truly need to replace the value in `ts_train`, you can use the [DataFrame replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) command which allows you to replace the value dynamically

Comment: Thank you! this is what i need

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```
ts_train.replace(ts_train.values, train_data_scaled)
```

Comment: Thank you! this is what i need

Comment: @DavidFIM glad to help :)